# Why is this PHP warning (division by zero) being thrown?

Tags: php, warnings

I was receiving a PHP warning for 'Division By Zero' due to one of the equations on my site:

```
$VidListAppRate = (($VLA['Likes'] / $VLA['views']) * 100;
```

After I realized I did not account for the fact that the variable **$VLA['views']** could be zero, I changed this code to the following, thinking it would eradicate the warning:

```
$VidListAppRate = ($VLA['views'] === 0) ? 0 : ($VLA['Likes'] / $VLA['views']) * 100;
```

However, the warning still appeared (note: **$VLA['views']** is an int) . I tried replacing 0 with a string:

```
$VidListAppRate = ($VLA['views'] === 0) ? 'N/A' : ($VLA['Likes'] / $VLA['views']) * 100;
```

but still I receive the warning. I know notices, warnings, and error messages in my php error_log are my friends, but how would I rewrite my code to appease this warning?

Comment: Maybe it's `'0'`? You're using the string equality check (`===`) which will not detect a 0 stored as a string. What does `var_dump($VLA['views'])` output anyway?

Comment: Change to `==`, not `===`

Comment: setting $a = var_dump($VLA['views']); outputted:      var_dump()

Comment: @ChemBlob9999: You're lying then ;) `var_dump()` wouldn't give that output. Is it `int(0)` or `string(1) "0"`?

Comment: Sorry...I messed up at first :) Maybe I am using this incorrectly...never used var_dump

Comment: @ChemBlob9999: It's okay. It's not too hard once you get to know it. `var_dump()` is just a function that makes debugging easier (by dumping the contents of a variable - along with its types, values etc.). The usage is really simple. To inspect the contents of `$var`, you just do: `var_dump($var);` — no `echo` is required as `var_dump()` outputs the content on its own.

Comment: OK...even though the answer below eradicated the warning (== 0 instead of === 0), I will try to implement var_dump for my learning purposes

Comment: OK @Amal Murali...you're right. Finally saw the output because my div's background-color was #000....changed to #fff. Says for one of the values of $VLA['views'] (it's actually an array), took $VidListViewsArray[0])....outputted string(3) (value in this case was 206 views)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exact match is expected here:

```
$VidListAppRate = ($VLA['views'] === 0)...
```

Maybe you need:

```
$VidListAppRate = ($VLA['views'] == 0)...
```

Or:

```
$VidListAppRate = ($VLA['views'] === '0')...
```

Or:

```
$VidListAppRate = (!$VLA['views'])...
```

Comment: `($VLA['views'] == 0)` is the best option, IMO.

Comment: OK...the error message disappeared. Why is == required instead of === ? The table stores integers that can equal any integer including 0.

Comment: It seems that whatever you are using to pull the data from the DB is assigning everything is a string value. Do a var_dump($VLA); to confirm.

Comment: OK...will try to do this